# How to generate an android APK file using React Native?

Tags: android, react-native

I am new to App development. I am trying to build a basic android application that just displays "Hello world" when opened on the phone. I have created a project in react native and I am using the Expo-cli to view my outputs.

I want to generate an android APK file for that project. Is it possible to do it using Expo-cli and not use other software such as Android Studio? My ultimate aim is to build an application that can be shared with others and can be opened by just one touch on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading "Building Standalone Apps" for expo: https://docs.expo.io/distribution/building-standalone-apps/